# Navigation table not aligning properly in Chrome

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

On one of my old sites, which has a pretty messy and outdated code, I am having problems with navigation menu in Chrome. It aligns perfectly in Firefox and IE but for some reason in Chrome only first 3 tabs get properly centered.

http://jsfiddle.net/8b2Cm/1/

```
<table width="765"  border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
```

```
<td valign="top">
<table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

  <tr valign="top">

    <td width="19%"><a href="http://LINK"><img src="http://LINK" alt="" width="331" height="95" border="0"></a></td>

    <td width="81%"><img src="http://LINK/images/logo.jpg" alt="" width="434" height="95"></td>

  </tr>

</table>
</td>
```

```
<td valign="top" class="back1"><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

  <tr valign="top">

    <td width="1%"><img src="http://LINK/images/left-top.jpg" width="23" height="30" alt=""></td>

    <td width="98%" valign="middle"><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

      <tr>

        <td><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

          <tr>

            <td width="90%" class="left-text11"><div align="center"><a href="http://LINK" title="" class="left-text11"> Home</a></div></td>

            <td width="10%"><img src="http://LINK/images/line1.jpg" width="8" height="30" alt=""></td>

          </tr>

        </table></td>

        <td><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

          <tr>

            <td width="90%" class="left-text11"><div align="center" class="left-text11">

            <? if(!$_SESSION['sbprj_userid'])

        {

        ?><a href="http://LINK/register/" title="Registration" class="left-text11"><strong>Signup</strong></a>

        <?

        }else

        {

        ?><a href="http://LINK/myaccount.php" title="My Account" class="left-text11">My Account</a>

        <?

        }

        ?></div></td>

            <td width="10%"><img src="http://LINK/images/line1.jpg" width="8" height="30" alt=""></td>

          </tr>

        </table></td>

        <td><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

          <tr>

            <td align="center" width="90%" class="left-text11"><div align="center"><a href="http://LINK/free-poker-money/" title="Get Free Poker Money" class="left-text11">Free Poker Money </a></div></td>


          </tr>

        </table></td>

        <td><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

          <tr>



            <td width="10%"><img src="http://LINK/images/line1.jpg" width="8" height="30" alt=""></td>

          </tr>

        </table></td>

        <td><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

          <tr>

            <td align="center" width="90%" class="left-text11"><div align="center"><a href="http://LINK//" title="" class="left-text11">Poker School</a></div></td>


          </tr>

        </table></td>

        <td><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

          <tr>



            <td width="10%"><img src="http://LINK/images/line1.jpg" width="8" height="30" alt=""></td>

          </tr>

        </table></td>

        <td class="left-text11"><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">





          <tr>

            <td width="90%" class="left-text11"><div align="center"><a href="http://LINK/news/" title="News" class="left-text11">News </a></div></td>

            <td width="10%"><img src="http://LINK/images/line1.jpg" width="8" height="30" alt=""></td>

          </tr>



        </table></td>

        <td class="left-text11"><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">





          <tr>

            <td width="90%" class="left-text11"><div align="center"><a href="http://LINK/support/" title="Contact Us" class="left-text11">Support </a></div></td>

            <td width="10%"><img src="http://LINK/images/line1.jpg" width="8" height="30" alt=""></td>

          </tr>



        </table></td>

        <td class="left-text11"><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">





          <tr>

            <td width="90%" class="left-text11"><div align="center"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pokercash4free" target="_blank" title="Facebook" class="left-text11"><img src="http://LINK/images/facebook.png" border="0" width="28" height="25" /></a> <a href="https://twitter.com/pokercashfofree" target="_blank" title="Twitter" class="left-text11"><img src="http://LINK/images/twitter.png" border="0" width="28" height="25" /></a> <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/112112204165108610596/112112204165108610596/" target="_blank" title="Google+" class="left-text11"><img src="http://LINK/images/googleplus.png" border="0" width="28" height="25" /></a></div></td>


          </tr>



        </table></td>




      </tr>



    </table></td>

    <td width="1%"><img src="http://LINK/images/right-top.jpg" width="24" height="30" alt=""></td>

  </tr>

</table></td>
```

```
<td valign="top"><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

  <tr valign="top">

    <td width="1%"><img src="http://LINK/images/top-1.jpg" width="23" height="17" alt=""></td>

    <td width="98%" class="back2"><img src="http://LINK/images/back2.jpg" width="9" height="17" alt=""></td>

    <td width="1%"><img src="http://LINK/images/right-1.jpg" width="24" height="17" alt=""></td>

  </tr>

</table></td>
```

This is the code, any suggestions on how to fix this ?

Comment: The best fix is not to use table based design, let alone _nested_ table based design. That could be fixed with a simple `ul`. Also, please don't just paste all your code and expect us to struggle through it to try and find the problematic areas. Try to isolate or replicate the exact problem, it makes it easier for us.

Comment: In the first links, you are putting the link and image seperator in the same table. Later when it starts to break you put them in seperate tables. But you really should use a UL list for this instead, much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mess with separators.
Some separators are inside table(horizontal table with tabs, by the way, you should put only that table into fiddle and code, not whole the mess making for us harder to understand) cells, other separators come all alone in separate column, therefore they are taking the same place as column. Check it and move them, like it's done in first two tabs

Comment: Thank you, now it was simple :)